# Rendering a list on initial page using react-native for Android

Tags: android, react-native

[image]

Hi everyone,

I am new to Android development using react-native and I got this error which I have no idea where this come from because I am not using ScrollView at all!
I am trying to render a list on the initial screen and its data is coming from an api call.

My code is

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import {
      Image,
      ListView,
      TouchableHighlight,
      Text,
      View,
      StyleSheet
    } from 'react-native';
    import Api from '../../Utils/api';
    import CategoryRow from './CategoryRow';

    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
      container: {
        flex: 1,
        padding: 12,
        flexDirection: 'row',
        alignItems: 'center',
      },
      text: {
        marginLeft: 12,
        fontSize: 16,
      },
      photo: {
        height: 40,
        width: 40,
        borderRadius: 20,
      },
      separator: {
        flex: 1,
        height: StyleSheet.hairlineWidth,
        backgroundColor: '#8E8E8E',
      }
    });

    class Main extends React.Component {

      constructor(props){

        super(props);
        const ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2});

        this.state = {
          dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(['row 1', 'row 2'])
        }
      }

      componentDidMount(){

        Api.getCategories()
          .then((res) => {
            this.setState({
              dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(res)
            })
          })
          .catch();
      }

      render() {
        return(

          <ListView
            style={styles.container}
            dataSource = {this.state.dataSource}
            renderRow={(data) => <CategoryRow {...data} />}
          />

        )
      }
    }

    module.exports = Main;
```

And the code for categoryRow is:

```
    import React from 'react';
    import { View, Text, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
      container: {
        flex: 1,
        padding: 12,
        flexDirection: 'row',
        alignItems: 'center',
      },
      text: {
        marginLeft: 12,
        fontSize: 16,
      },
      photo: {
        height: 40,
        width: 40,
        borderRadius: 20,
      },
    });

    const CategoryRow = (props) => (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.text}>
          ${props.name}
        </Text>
      </View>
    );

    export default CategoryRow;
```

Example of data :

```
[
  {
    "categoryId": 1,
    "code": "15",
    "name": "Photography",
    "description": "Are you a photo junkie? Then join the “snap pack” and travel to some of the most photogenic places on earth. Our photography trips put you on an itinerary specially geared towards getting the perfect pic, with a group of like-minded travellers. Learn new tricks, share your knowledge, and never worry about taking the time to get the shot. Bonus: someone always has an extra lens cap.",
    "categoryTypeId": 1,
    "categoryType": {
      "categoryTypeId": 1,
      "name": "Activity"
    }
  }
]
```

Can someone please help me to find out where is the problem and how to resolve this error?

Answer (score 1):

I think ListView uses the ScrollView props. See here http://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.35/docs/listview.html#scrollview

From the error, it seems you should specify `alignItems: 'center'` in the `contentContainerStyle` prop of the `ListView`. Remove it from `styles.container`

```
<ListView contentContainerStyle={{alignItems: 'center'}}>
    ....
</ListView>
```

Comment: So you mean I have to wrap ListView with ScrollView ?

Answer (score 0):

```
  render() {
    return(
       <View style={{
          alignItems: 'center'
        }}>
           <ListView
              style={styles.container}
              dataSource = {this.state.dataSource}
              renderRow={(data) => <CategoryRow {...data} />}
           />)
     </View>
  }
```